# How do I set/get heap size for Spark (via Python notebook)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ipython, anaconda

I'm using Spark (1.5.1) from an IPython notebook on a macbook pro. After installing Spark and Anaconda, I start IPython from a terminal by executing: `IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark`. This opens a webpage listing all my IPython notebooks. I can select one of them, opening it in a second webpage. SparkContext (sc) is available already, and my first command in the notebook is `help(sc)`, which runs fine. The problem I'm having is that I am getting a Java heap space error that I don't know how to address. How do I view my current Java heap setting, and how do I increase it within the context of my setup. The error message I'm getting follows:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 19 in stage 247.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 19.0 in stage 247.0 (TID 953, localhost): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: when are you having the error? trying to do what?

Comment: Create an RDD of LabeledPoint. It is not particularly huge, 100K observations x2K feature vector.

Answer (score 20):

You can manage Spark memory limits programmatically (by the API).

As SparkContext is already available in your Notebook:

```
sc._conf.get('spark.driver.memory')
```

You can set as well, but you have to shutdown the existing SparkContext first:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("App")
conf = (conf.setMaster('local[*]')
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '4G')
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '45G')
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10G'))
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

If your workload is the same for all analysis, then editing **spark-defaults.conf** as cited above is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by creating a **`spark-defaults.conf`** file in `apache-spark/1.5.1/libexec/conf/` and adding the following line to it:
**`spark.driver.memory 14g`**

That solved my issue. But then I ran into another issue of `exceeding max result size of 1024MB`. The solution was to add another line in the file above:
**`spark.driver.maxResultSize 2g`**

Comment: 14g is not a lot??? It's not big data but it is actually a lot!

Comment: Great answer and the only that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `config` option when setting SparkSession (as of 2.4)

```
MAX_MEMORY = "5g"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Foo") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: i get the error :This SparkContext may be an existing one.

Comment: Just replace you code by this one, instead of adding it.
The message said that you already created one session,

Comment: `spark.stop()` also useful if spark is running at the time